# dynamically extracting an element from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame and I want to call a specific column with specific values.

Like this:

```
the.dataframe$gender[the.dataframe$gender=="male"]
```

or this:

```
male <- subset(the.dataframe, gender == 1, select = gender)
```

What I have been unable to do is to make it so I can change the gender variable dynamically since the $ can't use objects:

```
x <- "gender"
male <- subset(the.dataframe, x == 1, select = x)
```

I think I saw the answer somewhere, but I have been unable to relocate it :/

----EDIT----

I finally found what I believe to be the best solution.
The comment from *thelatemail* helped me along but the solution returns the whole data frame when I only want the column in question.
I knew about [[ ]] command, but was unsure on how it worked.
Finally after a few tests I did:

```
x <- gender
the.dataframe[[x]][the.dataframe[[x]]=="male"]
```

the solution from Michele Usuelli only returns the correct column as my problem was to return specific cases from a column.
The answer from Roth Das works perfectly, but I find the setup a bit confusing.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, perhaps `ifelse(TFtest, what to do if T, what to do if F)`?

Comment: `the.dataframe[the.dataframe[[x]]=="male",]`

Comment: Instead of editing the answer that worked best for you into the question, it would be best to add it as an answer to the question. You can do that by clicking the "Post Your Answer" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternale version of above if you want to access other columns too.

```
colname <- "gender"
df[df[,colname] == "male",colname]
```

Comment: I liked this answer, but found it to be more complex when reading than:

x <- gender

the.dataframe[[x]][the.dataframe[[x]]=="male"]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [[

```
name_column <- "gender"
the.dataframe[[name_column]]
```